# Best way to fix bad count on All | Mine | Published

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, filters, hooks, views

I tweaked the default behavior of the post listing page (for a custom post type) via pre_get_posts, the thing is that now the count of `All | Mine | Published` isn't the right one.

I'm aware there is this filter: `views_edit-{post_type}`

But we are editing the HTML output, so to correct this value i'm currently doing :

`$views['all'] = preg_replace("/\(\d+\)/", "($new_count)", $views['all']);`

Which I find it dirty, I'm aware of the filter `wp_count_posts` which return this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [publish] => 38
    [future] => 0
    [draft] => 0
    [pending] => 0
    [private] => 0
    [trash] => 0
    [auto-draft] => 0
    [inherit] => 0
    [request-pending] => 0
    [request-confirmed] => 0
    [request-failed] => 0
    [request-completed] => 0
    [acf-disabled] => 0
)
```

But `All` and `Mine` are missing, so I can't change those with this filter, there is a better way of doing it ?

**EDIT**
The "tweak":

```
function custom_filter_devis_list(WP_Query $query) {
   if ($query->get('post_type') !== 'devis') return;
   if (current_user_can('administrator')) return;
   if ($query->is_main_query() && is_admin()) {
      $query->set('meta_key', 'partenaire');
      $query->set('meta_value', get_current_user_id());
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_filter_devis_list');
```

But as far as I'm aware, this is supposed to mess up the count process when altering the listing with `pre_get_posts`, I found stackoverflow post fixing it by using `views_edit-{post_type}`, but to me it seems like a dirty fix

Comment: What was "the tweak"?  Seems like that is where you should be looking?

Comment: I added the tweak in the edit